# Does a Spectator need to make an attack roll to determine whether it hits a target with its Eye Rays?

Tags: dnd-5e, monsters, saving-throw, attack-roll

The spectator is a D&D monster that can shoot rays out from its eyes with varying effects. The creature it targets has to succeed on a DC 13 saving throw (the ability of the save depends on the type of eye ray) to avoid one of the eye rays' effects).

Does the spectator have to make an attack roll first to determine whether the ray hits its target or misses?

Comment: Have you read through the basic rules/srd yet?

Comment: yes i have, i just got it delivered today, sorry about before.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

## No, its Eye Rays don't require attack rolls

Saving throw mechanics are different from attack mechanics. The DC for the Eye Ray is static and the target simply has to make the save, just like any other save effect, whether it's from a spell, an eye ray, a trap, or anything else.

If it required an attack roll, it would say so and provide the modifiers, as it does for its Bite attack.

### The good news

While its Wounding Ray does give it a guaranteed-damage option, it's important to remember that the Spectator is not just a stat block that needs to be optimized. It's a character in your story and it's crazy, so play it crazy! Have fun with it - these aberrations don't follow our rules.

Comment: Thank you, but with its wounding ray, it says that if you exceed the Constitution DC you still take half the damage as it would've if you hadn't exceeded the DC. It can't be that every time it uses the wounding eye-ray, it does damage.

Comment: @MorthosTimor each time it uses it, the target must make the save. but yes, it is pretty much automatic damage every round that they use the wounding eye ray.

Comment: @MorthosTimor And yes, it does damage each time, regardless of whether the target makes the DC save or not (although it does less damage if the target makes the save).

Comment: It may be worth noting that some classes get special abilities that let them resist some of the damage from effects that require saves. Rogues and Monks get Evasion at level 7 that lets them always ignore half the damage of effects that require them to make a Dex save for half damage (so they take none on a success and half on a failure).

Comment: @MorthosTimor The same is true of any damaging spell or ability that has a saving throw for half damage. Spells like "fireball" or abilities like a dragon's breathe weapon would also be considered "automatic damage" by the same logic.

Comment: But it's the DM's job to make sure the monster doesn't use those attacks every time, making it a fairer battle